# Hide Admob ads view in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, admob

I put an Admob banner at the bottom centre of screen using the following code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                                 self.view.frame.size.height -
                                 CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height);
    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner
                                                 origin:origin];
    bannerView_.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.frame.size.height-CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height/2);
    bannerView_.adUnitID = @"myid";
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}
```

However, in iPad, I plan to put different ads on another location. Therefore, I need to hide this ads in iPad. Is it possible for me to do this?

Comment: bannerView_ .hidden = YES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to make more than one banner view. The easier solution is using the same banner view but checking the current device idiom before positioning the view.  For example here is the code you provided modified to check which device the user is on:

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView*) webView
{
    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                                 self.view.frame.size.height -
                                 CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height);
    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner
                                                 origin:origin];
    bannerView_.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.frame.size.height-CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height/2);

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        // Change the banner's center/origin here for the iPad.
    }

    bannerView_.adUnitID = @"myid";
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
bannerView_.hidden=true;
```

Comment: This is bad, because Admob will probably still load into the view even though it is hidden. It will still be an impression.